# Angular 2 SVG will not load when using router, refresh page and it will render

Tags: html, angular, typescript, svg

I am using svg-icon package and displaying svgs like this :

```
<svg-icon src="./assets/images/pintrest.svg" [stretch]="true" [svgStyle]="{'width.px':30,'fill':'rgb(150,50,255)','padding.px':1,'margin.px':3}">
</svg-icon>
```

When on Home page they render fine. When routing to my login page icons will not render. Console logs this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at SvgIconRegistryService.loadSvg (angular-svg-icon.js:25)
    at SvgIconComponent.init (angular-svg-icon.js:109)
    at SvgIconComponent.ngOnChanges (angular-svg-icon.js:93)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12407)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13935)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13878)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14771)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14712)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (FooterComponent.html:12)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14697)
View_FooterComponent_0 @ FooterComponent.html:12
proxyClass @ compiler.js:14659
DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:15038
ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1510
(anonymous) @ core.js:5925
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
Zone.run @ zone.js:138
NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:4708
ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:5925
(anonymous) @ core.js:5751
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:4760
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
Zone.run @ zone.js:138
NgZone.run @ core.js:4577
next @ core.js:5751
schedulerFn @ core.js:4342
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:243
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:190
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:131
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:95
Subject.next @ Subject.js:56
EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:4322
checkStable @ core.js:4725
onHasTask @ core.js:4773
ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:441
ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:461
Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:285
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:205
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:500
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:485
timer @ zone.js:2054
setTimeout (async)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2075
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:255
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1114
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2090
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1394
(anonymous) @ router.js:4837
schedulerFn @ core.js:4342
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:243
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:190
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:131
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:95
Subject.next @ Subject.js:56
EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:4322
(anonymous) @ common.js:172
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:4751
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
```

If I refresh page, svgs render and everything is fine. If anyone has any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It might be an issue where the image isn't found because of the http vs https encoding. Also, the image might not be found if the home page index.html is different than the router link home. In this case, put the base_url in the image link

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15996 might be a helpful resource. Again it might be a .htaccess issue